# Can I have subsites inherit permissions from the top node but also add subsite specific permissions without breaking inheritance?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I'm a little confused about how sharepoint permissions are propagated. Leaving inheritance on, I go to my subsite and grant "group1" the read permissions level. But now if I view the permissions at the site collection level I see that group has was given read access there to. So does this mean I can't have some permissions inherited from the root and add uninherited permissions for specific sites? This is how AD permissions works and I'm surprised sharepoint doesn't do this.

With AD permissions inheritance I can do something like this:
-Top level folder: 
    group1 read access
--Sub Folder: 
    group1 read access (inherited from Top), 
    group2 read access (not inherited)
---Sub Sub Folder: 
    group1 read access (inherited from Top), 
    group2 read access (inherited from Sub Folder),
    group3 read access (not inherited)

I want to give some groups access at the top of the site collection and have that propagated via inheritance down to all my site. I then want to give other groups access to specific sites without breaking inheritance. Is this possible or am I misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is expected behavior. but their is workaround of this.

- Create a group on root level without assigning any permission.
- Go to http//serverame/subsite/_layouts/user.aspx (Sub site permission
  page: subsite--> site settings > site permissions)
- Click on stop inheriting permissions button( BUT dont remove any body from the permission)
- Click on Grant Permissions button. Now you will be prompted to Grant
  Permission Model dialog window.
- Type the newly created group    name(Finance) in the Users/Groups
  input field
- In the next section    Click on Grant user permission directly option
  box. Now select the    permission (e.g contribute) to above mentioned
  group
- Click on Ok button.

Comment: Great I'll give this a shot. Another question though, would I find this procedure in the official Microsoft docs as well (tried googling, but did find anything). I only ask because it would be nice to reference a kb that explains this in terms of a best practices or even know issues document.